# Merge logging config of Spring boot and Logback

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I have a following situation: A spring boot app using logback and several logging properties configured already in `application.yml`

I would like to add other config options that are only available via `logback.xml` file but as soon as i add this file to the classpath (does not matter if it is named `logback.xml` or `logback-spring.xml`) it overrides everything from `application.yml` and all logging levels/patterns and other options defined there stop having effects - it seems that after adding `logback.xml` all options from `appication.yml` are ignored and i would need to readd them in the xml file instead of yml.

My question is: **is it possible to merge these two configs?** I mean i only need to add one option to logback.xml and i do not want to force every other developer to learn logback.xml syntax while they are already familiar with `application.yml` way of configuring logging.

**UPDATE1**

One of things i am trying to do is to enable logback JMX access, therefore i create a `logback-spring.xml` file with following contents:

```
<configuration debug="true">
   <jmxConfigurator />
</configuration>
```

Right after i introduce this file i lose all logging from the webapp even if i have `logging.level.root: info` in the `application.yml` file.

I would also like to keep using root logging level and pattern as it is defined in the `application.yml`. I also want to configure several `turboFilters` which are specific to logback and, from my knowledge, can only be degined via logback configuration file.

**UPDATE 2**

Both @devatherock and @Ashish Patil asnwers helped me with the issue, i have been aware of the possibility to include spring configuration elements in `logback.xml` via `springProperty` but i have not seen it as a viable solution since i would have to rewrite multiple elements this way making the `logback.xml` harder to read.

But as @devatherock mentioned - by default the config files **ARE** merged it is that logback requires the existence of appender and root logger in its configuration. Even when present in the `logback.xml` file the root logger level will still be overwritten by `application.yml` setting (which is desired) but the `pattern` property will not and we have to use `springProperty` for that.

So while both answers were helpful but actually @devatherock's insignts were more helpful for me i am included to accept his answer.

Comment: I have used logback with spring boot and haven't seen this happen before. Can you specify which spring boot version you are using and provide sample `application.yml` and `logback.xml` files?

Comment: I think sample files are not relevant here i do not have anything specific in my configuration. It is that adding logback.xml to the classpath makes the logging library ignore everything logging related that is defined in application.yml. So i would like to, for example, configure some advanced things in logback.xml but still keep the possibility of defining logging levels in application.yml

Comment: Include the base logging config from Spring Boot with `<include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />`. Which should give you the boot defaults and the property binding for patterns etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample project, [spring-boot-logback](https://github.com/devatherock/spring-boot-logback) which specifies logging config in both `logback.xml` and `application.yml`

The `root` log level gets set to `WARN` in the logback.xml which looks like below:

```xml
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <withJansi>true</withJansi>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="WARN">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

There is a controller method that handles `/hello`, with a `DEBUG` and a `INFO` log line. The log level for the controller class is set to `DEBUG` in the `application.yml` file which looks like below:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    io.github.devatherock.demo.controller: DEBUG
```

I started the application and hit the `/hello` controller endpoint. Below are the log lines that I saw:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.7)

08:41:45.051 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG i.g.d.d.controller.HelloController - Debug log in sayHello method
08:41:45.052 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  i.g.d.d.controller.HelloController - Info log in sayHello method
```

None of the application startup logs are present because the root log level is set to WARN in the logback.xml. Both the debug and info log lines from the controller are present because the controller log level has been set to DEBUG in the application.yml. Thus we can confirm that logging config from both logback.xml and application.yml are applied without any issues

**Update 1:**

Looks like if a `logback.xml` is specified, at a minimum, it needs to have the appender, encoder and the attachment of appender to root log level, for the logging config overrides using spring boot's `logging.*` properties to work. Once I specified such a `logback.xml` file with also the `jmxConfigurator`, I was able to adjust the root and controller log levels in the `application.yml`. The new `logback.xml` and `application.yml` files below:

**logback.xml with jmxConfigurator:**

```xml
<configuration>
    <jmxConfigurator />
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

**application.yml with root log level:**

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    root: WARN
    io.github.devatherock.demo.controller: DEBUG
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your time to check, you are correct setting per-logger logging levels DOES work as intended. I have updated my original question with more info - basically - is it possible to skip configuring root logger/appender/pattern in the xml file and use those defined in application.yml? I also would like to use several other options which are only possible trhough logback.xml (and as i have shown even creating an empty logback.xml already changes how my application logging behaves)

Answer (score 1):

Use of [springProperty](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.logging.logback-extensions.environment-properties) might be suitable for your requirement.

Let's say ,you have `application.yml` like below:

```
logging:
  level:
    root: DEBUG
...  // other configs
```

Now you want to enforce configs of application.yml even after having `logback.xml`, then you can add `springProperty` in your `logback.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <jmxConfigurator />
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="loggerProperty" source="logging.level.root"/>
    
    <root level="${loggerProperty}">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
    ... //other configurations.
</configuration>
```

Now, here when you start your spring-boot, you can see application.yml's config value is getting read instead of overriding.

So by this way , you can have as many properties configured in `logback` &  in `application.yml`.

Basically, you are referring `Environment` properties (which are defined in your application.properties / application.yml) from your logback.

Here `logging.level.root` is environment property which is defined  `application.yml` & you referred it in `logback.xml` by giving it a name as `loggerProperty`. You are then using this `loggerProperty` within your logback so that it will get used instead of logback's default one.